The Difference Between Hegel and Schelling on Persons?
While clear differences exist between Schelling and Hegel's philosophies, can we say that the key move lies in the former's adoption of personalism, while the latter is an impersonalist?
The beef between both is well documented and does not need to be rehashed here. But it is often said that Schelling's mature thought, relying on the distinction between negative (human to the divine) and positive (divine to human encounter) philosophy, is merely a form of theosophy. Or that it is anti-Hegelian. Or that it is post-idealist. Yet it would be wrong to categorize Schelling's philosophy as "existentialist" despite anticipating many of those later ideas because, as the great Fred Copleston notes in Volume VII of his classic A History of Philosophy: "illustrious minds of the past should not blind us to the great differences in atmosphere between the idealist and existentialist movements" (148). There are a number of ways that Schelling's mature thought may be described. None of these cheap labels are inaccurate, but they still fail to capture the central thrust of Schelling's ultimate transformation as a thinker. Can we conclude with Copleston that: "In any case Schelling is perhaps most notable for his transformation of the impersonal Absolute of metaphysical idealism into the personal God who reveals himself to the religious consciousness"? (ibid.)

You've emphasized Schelling's mature philosophy (i.e. his later works; I'd rather call it that because mature gives a negative nuance to his earlier works).
While his later works indeed emphasize a bit more "personality" to the Absolute, I wouldn't say that Schelling's take on the Absolute is of "personalism". There are enough places where the Absolute is given an "impersonal" (or better put, pre-personal) take. For example, in Ages of The World:

"So near in all of us lies the unground (Ungrund) of eternity, before
which we cannot but shrink back in horror whenever it is brought to
consciousness."

Here we can see that the Absolute is the "unground", at least until it's being brought to consciousness - i.e. we cannot even comprehend it identify this "unground"edness, let alone emphasize with any personality it may or may not have.
Even the "identity" itself of the Absolute cannot be contained in a positive manner, rather only negative, e.g. from Human Freedom:

"... Thus it cannot be designated as the identity of opposites, but only as
their absolute indifference"

Alas, regarding the subjective aspect of personality in the Absolute's actions, see:

"When the eternal decided to lift itself out of concealment by positing at its beginning the force and power of its contraction, it thereby fell into a condition of blind action. Even in this condition, however, it was able only to act in conformity with the divinity of its nature, that is, as the most supreme and perfect being must act. Creation was not a conscious act, for even if it posited itself immediately in that original deed as subject, it related itself to itself as to something that had to first be posited.".


In conclusion, the Absolute for Schelling, is the dynamic *primordial* "unground" - and with that, it may have both objective *and* subjective nuances; but it's mainly devoid of these distinctions (because it precedes them).

Perhaps a more exact distinction would be between Hegel's pre-determined, rational Absolute; and Schelling's creatively dynamic, primordial Absolute.
I would add though, relating to my first paragraph, that I don't think separating Schelling's later works from his early works is quite productive; viewing his philosophy more holisticly is perhaps a better approach (and an approach that's gaining more traction; see e.g. Ian Hamilton Grant's Philosophies of Nature after Schelling (and more, such as Andrew Bowie, Jason Wirth).

In his Philosophy of Mythology and Revelation Schelling explicitly goes back to the "old metaphysics" that doesn't think in terms of "systems," as the moderns do. It is a serious mistake, on my interpretation, to conflate Schelling's earlier thinking in systems with his thinking that abandons and critiques the whole business of system-building.

We might want to leave this debate for Schelling's scholars; but a response might be: Schelling didn't "abandon" thinking in systems - the entire Schellingian project is built from both systematic thinking and dynamic, thematic thinking. It includes both negative and positive aspects of philosophy, the one does not comes instead of the other. The critique is on philosophies that simply focus only on one aspect (the negative), such as Hegel's (which is the focus of his critique).

I'm a Schelling scholar, but even I wasn't why does it need to be left in the hands of a cabal of experts? Isn't this an open forum to exchange ideas? The entire positive philosophy is about the theogonic process and the radical nature of experience. Comparing the Schelling of the System of Nature or the System of Transcendental Idealism with his later lectures is a false narrative. A thinker of Schelling's caliber never develops in linear fashion, as if there were an invariant continuum that you could put his thinking on a timeline. There were great ruptures in his philosophical journey.

@Peirceverance - awesome! I'm not, so that's why I'm relying on scholars such as Ian Grant to back my claims. Also I wouldn't exactly call this forum a place to "exchange ideas", more to ask questions and get answers, but that's a different topic. Anyways, I think on the contrary that seeing Schelling as a philosopher who develops his thought in a dynamic fashion within his own trajectory (coming up with the negative and positive distinctions is obviously a later realization - but one that does not necessarily denies the negative aspect) gives him more respect.

Grant is awesome! I would mention Jason Wirth, Bruce Matthews, and others! This is an exciting time to be studying Schelling. I totally agree with your assessment about Schelling's trajectory as a thinker being praise-worthy and notable for its development! It is a remarkable philosophy in so many ways, seen in its totality. I really like Eric Voegelin's analysis of Schelling in Vol. 25 of his Collected Works, entitled the "The Last Orientation." Be sure to get your hands on that--it is Schelling as a Spiritual Realist.

@Peirceverance amazing, I'll add it to my list :) I'm trying to get a CW edition for a long time.

It is well worth it. You will have to let me know what you think! I think you can find a more affordable copy on abebooks or another similar book selling site.

Short Answer
Hegel saw God as this big, impersonal, all-encompassing thing, like the whole universe thinking itself. Schelling, on the other hand, thought there was a personal God behind all that, a God who could actually interact with us.
Long Answer
So actually Hegel was all about this idea of "Geist," which is like this giant cosmic mind or spirit. Everything, including us, is just part of Geist figuring itself out. Personality, for Hegel, is like a pit stop on Geist's road trip – important, but ultimately just part of the bigger journey. The "Absolute" for Hegel isn't some dude in the sky, but the whole process of Geist unfolding. We're all in the Geist-mobile, but nobody's really driving.
Schelling, later in his life, wasn't feeling that. He thought Hegel's system was cool and all, but it missed something big: where did Geist even come from? Schelling said there's this deeper thing, a "God beyond God," that's like the source code of everything. It's beyond our understanding, but it's the reason anything exists at all. And here's the kicker: this source code isn't totally impersonal. It's the foundation for a personal God who's like, "Hey, I wanna chat!" and reveals himself to us.
So, the main difference: Hegel's God is like a giant, thinking universe, and we're just along for the ride. Schelling's God is more like a person who created the universe and can actually talk to us. Hegel's all about logic and systems, while Schelling adds this whole personal relationship thing, which is a pretty big deal. Schelling still respects Hegel's logic, but he says it can't explain everything. There's this mystery at the heart of things, and that mystery is, in a way, personal. It's not just a giant cosmic computer program running itself. There's someone behind the keyboard.
